# Continued fraction convergence inequality identity

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, continued-fractions

I was on the same article mentioned on here
[Continued fraction rate of convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2742752/continued-fraction-rate-of-convergence?answertab=active#tab-top).

What I did not understand was this identity used to prove the right hand side of the inequality.

$$
 \left| \alpha -\frac{p_n}{q_n} \right|< \frac{1}{q_n q_{n+1}}
$$

For the RHS, there is a theorem that says

$$
\frac{p_{n-1}}{q_{n-1}} - \frac{p_n}{q_n} = \frac{(-1)^n}{q_n q_{n-1}}
$$

So intuitively, I have that $\frac{1}{q_n q_{n+1}} = \left| \frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}} - \frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}} \right| \implies \left| \alpha -\frac{p_n}{q_n} \right| < \left| \frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}} - \frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}} \right|$

Assuming that the identity $ \left| \alpha -\frac{p_n}{q_n} \right|< \frac{1}{q_n q_{n+1}} = \left| \frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}} - \frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}} \right|$ holds true, it doesn't make sense to me. It is telling me that the difference from the $n$-th approximation to $\alpha$ is less than the difference from the $n$-th approximation to the $(n+1)$-th approximation.

If it is true, how can I dervive it?

Comment: The fact that it's true is simply a restatement of the fact that $\alpha$ is between the $n$th convergent and the $(n+1)$st convergent.